# jQuery Toggle in SharePoint using XSLT, but all the instances toggle not just the clicked one

Tags: toggle

I am having a problem with my XSLT, I am using SharePoint 2010 and I am building a custom front-end that will pull data from lists and render the data in a nice manner.  I have figured out how to use XSLT with HTML to render a SharePoint list, I wasn't able to add an image of my news feeds because my rep is too low but I will get it up!

Now here is where my problem starts:

I am using jQuery toggle to show/hide the body paragraph of this news feed.  The Continue Reading button is where my issue is, every time I click on the "Continue Reading" button in the lower right of each news post, it show/hides all the news items, not just the one I click on.

I have tried using Bootstrap collapse and now I am using jQuery Toggle() however I run into the same issue!  Take a look at my XSLT code snippet to display thee body paragraph and the corresponding jQuery code snippet that actives the show/hide toggle:

XSLT:

```
<tr class="spacer">
 <td valign="top" class="td-newscontent">
  <div class="news content">
   <!-- start excerpt -->
    <xsl:value-of select="@BodyExcerpt" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
     <div class="moving">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
     </div>
 <!-- end news excerpt -->
 <!-- start continue reading link -->

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<br class="continue-br" />]]></xsl:text>
 <a class="butt pull-right continue-right">Continue Reading</a><br /><br />
<!-- end continue reading link  -->
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$(".moving").hide();   
$(".butt").click(function() {
$(".moving").toggle("slow", function() {  
     });
     });
```

.moving is the actual @body being shown/hidden
.butt is the "continue reading" button (I know butt was a bad name to use)

I have read a few things on the net about "this" but I am not sure how to use it.

First time posting so I couldn't post any images, but when you click on "continue reading" all the body news articles expand then you click it again and all the body news items contract, what I would like it to do is open just the one I am clicking on!

I have a lot going on, everything is housed in SharePoint, using HTML5, Css3, jQuery and XSLT.  I started by using IDs but I switched to classes, not sure if that was a good idea but it functions, but not as intended.

Any help would be appreciative, I have been researching this issue for almost 2 weeks so I finally decided to ask some experts :) (Feel free to ask any questions or ask for more information, I will answer with everything I got!)

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are close, so well done for getting this far! Your problem lies in your JavaScript.  If you look at the rendered code using your browser's developer tools (F12), you will find that all of the different body texts have the same class (`moving`) and all of the buttons have the same JavaScript `onclick`, which is to toggle everything of class `.moving`.

Thus the solution you are looking for is to **match each button with its respective body text**.  There are two main ways you can do this.

1. You can give each text div and each button a unique ID by assigning it to some unique feature of the list item (SharePoint list items already have a unique identifier as the field `ID`).  Using `xsl:value-of` within HTML attributes would violate XML rules, so you can use something called an Attribute Value Template, which is the bit in the curly braces:

> ```
> <div id="newstext_{@ID}">
>    <xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
> </div>
> <!-- etc... -->
> <a onclick="$('#newstext_{@ID}').toggle('slow', function() {});">Continue reading</a>
> ```

2. Modify just the JavaScript to target the parent of the button.  The following code selects the parent DOM element of the button, which should be the div of class .news, then finds the child of class .moving, then applying your toggle:

> ```
>  $(".butt").click(function() {
>      $(this).parent().find(".moving").toggle("slow", function() {  
>      });
>  });
> ```

The second method is easier but can get complicated if you end up running a lot of JavaScript.  It is easier (and more efficient) to select elements by ID, so personally I think the extra effort is worth it. I haven't tested this code so let me know if it doesn't work. On some of your other points:

- no, `butt` is not a good name for a class - remember, you can use element types in your jQuery selectors, so there is no need to duplicate the type as the class.  For example, $('a') selects all the anchor tags on the page.
- IDs should be used when elements need to be uniquely identified (e.g. for scripts), classes when you are grouping elements together (e.g. for styles).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivan, I will defiantly try this out tomorrow at work and I will post back my results!